# Redirect to checkout in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

I am trying to implement the Stripe function "redirect to checkout" in ReactJS.
I have been looking around and there is no package that seems to help to do it.

```
const stripe = 
Stripe('key');

stripe.redirectToCheckout({
  items: [
    // Replace with the ID of your SKU
    {sku: 'sku_123', quantity: 1}
  ],
  successUrl: 'https://your-website.com/success',
  cancelUrl: 'https://your-website.com/canceled',
}).then(({error}) => {
  // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or 
network
  // error, display the localized error message to your 
customer
  // using `error.message`.
});
```

This is where I got this source code: https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#stripe-redirect-to-checkout

StripeJS only seems to support the standard checkout that does not receive the product SKU as the parameter

Comment: are you doing this on the frontend? O.o

Comment: I am a newbie to react. I was trying to find the easiest way to sell a subscription..https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/client

Comment: well, this isn't a React thing. React is a frontend library / framework. Stripe is a payment system, there is js support but its meant for a nodejs backend. I would recommend you set up a backend to do the payment stuff, and apis to talk to that backend. Or else someone can inspect your frontend code and steal stuff like access keys

Comment: Even the server integration has that method: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/server#create-subscriptions
I need to call that stripe.redirectToCheckout from React somehow..

Answer (score 13):

After I read the new `stripe-js` docs https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react
I found this might be useful for you

Instead using `stripe`, install `@stripe/stripe-js`
then the job can be done by

```
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";

...

const stripePromise = loadStripe(
    "pk_.........."
  );

const stripe = await stripePromise;

stripe.redirectToCheckout({
      ...
    })
```

Comment: Spot on! This solved the issue for me. I needed to use Stripe library in `useEffect` hook before I had a chance to inject the Stripe script in the head.

Answer (score 6):

I found out how ti make it work.

Basically as per the documentation, there is the need to import the Stripe script in public/index.html

```
stripe.redirectToCheckout(...)
```

can be simply put into the onClick of a button.
The thing that is really not clear in the docs, and that can mislead newbies like me, lies in setting the public key:

```
const stripe = Stripe('key');
```

doesn't work, because the script is not found at compile time.
This can be solved by using:

```
const stripe = window.Stripe('key');
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Or you could add it to your build tool-chain and consume it internally. You have to install with `npm i stripe` https://www.npmjs.com/package/stripe

Comment: As per the documentation, this key has permission to read all your product info