# redirectToCheckout Stripe Checkout with React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview, stripe-payments

Please help! I'm attempting to integrate Stripe's new version of Checkout (released April 2019) for one time payments with my React Native app.

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/one-time#redirect-checkout

I'm at Step 2: Redirect to Checkout as I've set up my Ruby on Rails Back End to the point where I'm able to provide my CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID, however when I attempt to run .redirectToCheckout on my Front End I'm getting an error that redirectToCheckout isn't a function. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: You may need to do the same thing as the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56551841/redirect-to-checkout-in-reactjs -- can you try that and let us know if it works for you?

Comment: Appreciate your response @taintedzodiac! Had found this thread before posting, but ran into issues from differences between ReactJS and React Native. Using Expo to build (yes I’ve ejected!), but struggling to create a usable instance of a Stripe Object. Starting from the top of Step 2, I'm using tipsi-stripe library + expo-payments-stripe instead of Stripe.js & I'm unable to embed a script tag in an index.js file. Attempted workaround here was to leverage react-native-webview. Not sure using webview makes sense, also not sure if I'm leveraging it properly... any additional thoughts or ideas?!

Comment: I'm using Stripe.setOptionsAsync({ publishableKey: 'i put my key in' }) to create an instance, which console logs as 'Promise {"_40": 0,"_55": null,"_65": 0,"_72": null,}' but I'm unable to call .redirectToCheckout on this instance (my error message reads... 'undefined is not a function'). Not sure if .redirectToCheckout function is unavailable with the libraries I'm using or if my error is due to leveraging react-native-webview improperly?

Comment: @atack did you find anything on it?